# Pasar parámetro a store procedure desde la consulta de otra tabla

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, parametros

a todos, tengo que alimentar una tabla de mi base de datos, con información que esta en archivos de excel, para ello cargo la información en una tabla temporal  usando

`BULK INSERT #CAMBIOS_TBL FROM 'C:\Samples\csv\Archivo.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =',',ROWTERMINATOR ='\n');`

Una vez ahí hago un insert a la  tabla cambios de mi base de datos haciendo un select de mi tabla temporal. ahora quiero tomar los  datos de mi tabla temporal, ver que existan en la tabla cambios y traerme el  folio  mi tabla cambios y pasarla como paramatro e un store procedure que ya ha sido creado.

Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Hola Bernardino, Por lo que comentas, entiendo que lo único que necesitas es saber como pasar el "folio" (el valor de un campo) de la tabla "cambios" a un store procedure, ¿correcto?

Comment: asi es es una carga masiva de registros que  tengo en excel hablo de mas de 3000 registros, es store procedure recibe como parámetro el folio del cambio, entonces lo que  intento hacer es tomar esos folios y pasarlos al store procedure para que afecte a mi tabla de historial de movimeintos

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que el valor de "Folio" lo tienes asignado a una variable llamada "@Folio", y que el stored procedure acepta 1 parámetro de entrada:

```
EXEC "Nombre del Stored Procedure" @Folio
```

Por ejemplo:

```
EXEC sp_GuardarFolio @Folio
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

**Edición**
Para enviar todos los datos de una consulta puedes utilizar un bucle While, por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @IDPk INT 
DECLARE @IDFolio INT 
DECLARE @TMPFolios TABLE (IDPk INT IDENTITY, IDFolio INT) 
INSERT INTO @TMPFolios (IDFolio) SELECT IDFolio FROM Cambios

SELECT TOP 1 @IDPk=IDPk, @IDFolio=IDFolio
    FROM @TMPFolios WHERE IDPk >@IDPk  ORDER BY 
IDPk 

WHILE @@ROWCount <> 0  
BEGIN   
EXEC sp_GuardarFolio @IDFolio

SELECT TOP 1 @IDPk=IDPk, @IDFolio=IDFolio
FROM @TMPFolios WHERE IDPk >@IDPk  ORDER BY 
IDPk  
END
```

Comment: Hola gracias, eso si lo entiendo, lo que  quiero hacer es tomar los  folios generados la tabla cambios y pasarlos como parámetro a otro store procedure llamado genera_historial  por ejemplo  tengo el folio 1,2,3,4,5. este es un ejemplo con cinco registros la verdad la cantidad de registros va mas de 3000 los que  debo insertar en cambios e histrial no se si me explique